# How to make my Android app appear in the share list of another specific app

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, share

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />     
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

this is in my manifest file

this will make my app appear on the share list of all apps
but I want my app to appear in the share list of another specific app
and I don't own the other app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to know the Intent that the application is creating and create an IntentFilter that will add your application to the specific list.

[*Receiving an Implicit Intent*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) on [Intents and Filters (Android Developers)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

The application probably uses a specific action name that you could hook to.

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_CURRENT" />
    <action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_RECENT" />
    <action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_PENDING" />
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

Or it could be looking for applications accepting a certain type of file.

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . /> 
    <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . />
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

The name of the application and what it is sharing would help me give a more specific response.

Comment: I want my app to appear on the share list of "Google play App" only. when you try to share app.  it share text, but a lot of other apps uses the same thing!!    

can I filter the content of the text??!!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Examining the Intent shows it truly is very general.

Answer (score 23):

Add this code in the activity you want opened first when sharing a content from outside the app, call this method in onCreate()

```
private void onSharedIntent() {
    Intent receiverdIntent = getIntent();
    String receivedAction = receiverdIntent.getAction();
    String receivedType = receiverdIntent.getType();

    if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {

        // check mime type 
        if (receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {

            String receivedText = receiverdIntent
                    .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if (receivedText != null) {
                //do your stuff
            }
        }

        else if (receivedType.startsWith("image/")) {

            Uri receiveUri = (Uri) receiverdIntent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

            if (receiveUri != null) {
                //do your stuff
                fileUri = receiveUri;// save to your own Uri object

                Log.e(TAG,receiveUri.toString());
            }
        }

    } else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onSharedIntent: nothing shared" );
    }
}
```

Add this in Manifest,

```
 <activity
            android:name="your-package-name.YourActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 15):

[image]**- Add below code into your Project AndroidManifest.xml file in Specific Activity.**

```
     <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

**- Add the following line of code into your project specific Activity.**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if ("android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action) && type != null && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
                Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"shareablTextExtra",intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT"));
            }
```

Comment: Hi @Bhavik any other permission add app side ?. i try but not working

Comment: Not actually required in my case. Which device did you try on?

Answer (score 9):

add this to your mainefist file

```
<activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
<intent-filter
    android:label="Share with my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

[this link may help you](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent/)

Answer (score 9):

this worked well for me for getting all web pages, for [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.specificapps.mp3_website_scanner_alarm) that scans for mp3 files on a web page, and sets alarms from them. It opens up my new url activity, when you share a web page:

Here is what this code results in:
[image]

```
  <activity
        android:name=".NewUrl"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_url"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then to receive the link in the app, I got awsome info from this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-receiving-data-from-the-send-intent--mobile-14878

Answer (score 6):

> I want to add something to the above answers. Keep in mind that you should put another intent filter to prevent overriding in case you are using multiple categories in an activity.

For example, the following will prevent your application to be shown on the application list in your device because it doesn't detect it as launcher activity.

#### Don't do this

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      
                <!-- DO NOT DO THIS-->

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
```

#### Instead do following

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- USE SEPERATE INTENT FILTER -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Note: Change mimeType according to your use.**

> Verdict: If you are using more than one category in intent filter use them separately.

Comment: It's help a lots. thanks. work fine on some China brand devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if there is any API for this app you want to work with.

If so, you can benefit by knowing

a more specific implicit action for your filter

or perhaps add a category other than DEFAULT

If you can find something like these, it would be unlikely to be seen by other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to have you Activity NOT labeled with `android:exported="false"`, otherwise it won't show up in other applications' intent choosers (only your own)

E.g. AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
     android:name=".ReceiveImageActivity"
     android:exported="true"> <!-- here -->
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```