# List android app in external share

Tags: android, share

I am working on an android app and have worked on the share external feature, in which I can share the content of my application to other applications installed on the phone.

Now what I want to implement is that when any app like if Facebook is installed in the phone and if we share any content from Facebook externally then it list all the application on which it can share the content. So, I want that my app should also be listed in the list of the apps on which the content can be shared.

So, I want to implement other app's content sharing in my application.

How can I achieve this. Thanks a lot in advanced for all the help :)

Comment: You can see here for some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i understand that you want send and listen data in you app

you can use intents for do this action

look this android documentation for receiving data http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sharing/receive.html

and this for send data to other app
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sharing/send.html

i hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

**Declare your activity in manifest as it can send data**

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[**Read Android Documentation for full Understanding**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/sharing/send.html)