# What is the IntentFilter that do my app be recognized like having audio to share?

Tags: android, intentfilter, whatsapp

What is the `IntentFilter` that I have to use in order to my app be recognized as like having audio to share? `WhatsApp` do not list my app anyway...

Like this:[image]

I already tried:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and too

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But nothing seems to work...

Anyone knows?

Thx

Comment: why have you used multiple <intent-filter> combine them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are looking for this, but try to use the mimeType audio:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

For more info visit [Android Intent-Filter Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score -1):

Add this in manifest:-

```
<intent-filter . . . >

<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

<action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_CURRENT" />
<action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_RECENT" />
<action android:name="com.example.project.SHOW_PENDING" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
. . .
</intent-filter>
```

Combine all `<intent-filter . . . >` 
I hope this should work, besides you can follow this guide [Guide link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799840/4762767)

Comment: Nothing :( Any other idea?

Comment: I'm new on this, I don't know if I get what you mean, what do you mean with intent in my activity? My activity does not send any intent, it want to receive a intent coming from whatsApp, in order to offer a sound to be shared via whatsapp then I have to use a intent-filter. I'm wrong?

Comment: Really thanks for your attention :), I read all tutorial and found out that my app is shown when I click in shared audio (long click in any audio), however it is not listed when I click in that clip button on whatsapp, why this happen? what I'm doing wrong? What I really want is that my app be listed when this clip button is clicked and then the user can choose a audio of my app, and this audio be send to whatsApp..., I and my friends was looking for a answer for months :(

Comment: Welcome, i have edited my answer with guide now, if its working you can vote up for me :p 
Happy Coding... :-)

Comment: Just is missing that it be listed when I click in the clip button on whatsApp. When my app is opened it send audio to whatsApp normally, but when the clip button is clicked (on whatsApp) and the list of app with audio avaiable to be shared is shown my app is not there... :(