# Share to React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to have apps on the android device to share to my react-native app. However, I can't find any documentation which can help me so I was wondering if there any way to share content from other apps to my app?

Clarification:
[image]

I am trying to add my app to this list

Comment: You can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app

Answer (score 1):

You need Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity. [reference here.](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

```
<intent-filter  android:label="Share here!">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

As you may notice, This *Witchcraft* will show your app on the Sharing list.

In order to handle the burden, place the next snippet in your component. Any component.

```
componentDidMount() {
        Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
            console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
        }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    }
```

This charm is called `Linking`. Documentation found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html)

Comment: Tried but url is always null