# I am not able to see my Android application in Share menu list while sharing pdf from adobe 18.3 version application

Tags: android, xamarin

I am not able to see my Android application in Share menu list while sharing pdf from Adobe 18.3 version application but below versions of Adobe app, I am able to see my app in Share menu.

Do I need to change in my Android to make it work?any ideas?

Please help me resolve the issue

Thank you,

Babu

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106806/8395242)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my Android app appear in the share list of another specific app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app)

Comment: Thank you andrew for your response.i have settings in my app same as per your link like [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend },
      Categories = new[] { "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" }, DataMimeType = "application/pdf")] ,it works fine adobe android application version 18.2 and below versions but not working with adobe android latest version 18.3

Comment: That sounds like a bug with the specific Adobe app version 18.3 then. Have you researched to see if this is a know bug or reached out to Adobe for assistance?

Comment: yes, I reached Adobe for assistance by posting the Bug and I am waiting for their response.thank you

Comment: Just curious, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Adobe community forums team reported to their Engineering team and waiting for their working solution

Comment: Looks like Adobe finally fixed the sharing issue. we can update latest Adobe from the play store, version 18.4.1, to resolve the error. 


Thank you,
Nagendra Babu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Adobe finally fixed the sharing issue. we can update latest Adobe from the play store, version 18.4.1, to resolve the error.

Thank you,

Nagendra Babu.