# React Native sharing articles and videos

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, react-native, share

[Typical sharing option in android image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TovO4.jpg)

Im looking to a way where i can use my app to share articles,images,videos etc using react native. My app name should be displayed ,i.e share via XYZ app(Like if you want to share posts from medium.com) and after which my XYZ app opens up exactly like whatsapp and theres a little preview on what is going to be sent , and after i click send, it should be sent to the desired user. Not exactly looking towards the sending part. First step of mine is to make the media(image,post,video etc) be shareable via my app and must have a preview on whats going to be sent.

Keeping it short:

1. How do i make my app be listed in the share option for any media type like image,video,posts etc?
   2.How do i preview the data that needs to be sent?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app

You will most probably need to do a little bit of native coding in order to make this possible, the above link is only for android

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ Thank you. This is what i was exactly i was looking for.

Comment: @GauravRoy happy to help :)