# How to make application be an option for sharing?

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

So, if you go to google photos, (Or literally any app that lets you share content), and click share, there are tons of options for sharing. How do I make my app be one of those options?

[image: Sharing ability]

When I google "Android app share options" all the results are how to add a sharing ability into your app. I need to make my app be an asset through which you can share, not something which shares. How do I do this? Do I need to use android actions? Declare something in the manifest? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: It works! Just what I needed. Thank you, CommonsWare!

Comment: **See this code you will get answer** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app