# how to make android suggest my app for opening location sent from whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I have added a deep link in manifest

i added this host "maps.google.com" that i found from whatsapp location
but that s not working

I tried

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="maps.google.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/maps"
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data
        android:host="maps.google.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/maps"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

and just like other deep links defined in manifest i expect android suggest the app in disambiguation dialog ...can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make my Android app appear in the share list of another specific app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095122/how-to-make-my-android-app-appear-in-the-share-list-of-another-specific-app)

Comment: @PrimožIvančič No, that's for sharing, not opening locations.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement a [Geo Service Activity](https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/Android-Geo-howto)

The Geo Service Activity catches android.intent.action.VIEW from online mapservices. Here is a working example:

[Manifest](https://github.com/k3b/AndroidGeo2ArticlesMap/blob/main/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<!-- get geo-location from online mapservices (google, yandex, here, openstreetmap)  -->
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:host="maps.google.de" />
    <data android:host="www.openstreetmap.org" />
    <data android:host="openstreetmap.org" />
    <data android:host="maps.yandex.ru" />
    <data android:host="maps.yandex.com" />
    <data android:host="here.com" />
    <data android:host="www.here.com" />
    <data android:host="share.here.com" />
    <data android:host="goto.here.com" />
    <data android:host="go.here.com" />
    <data android:host="wego.here.com" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Geo Service Activity](https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/blob/master/demo-geoHelper/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/demo_geohelper/GeoViewerDemoActivity.java)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    
    if (intent != null) {
        Object uri = intent.getData();
        message.append(MessageFormat.format("Received action:{0}\n - data:{1}\n", intent.getAction(), uri));

        if (uri != null) {
    // parse uri
            .... process uri
```

Comment: thank you so much link to manifest in github solved my problem...

Comment: but still cant deep link google map link to our app and i added these hosts: <data
                    android:host="maps.google.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/maps"
                    android:scheme="https" /><data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="maps.app.goo.gl"
                    android:pathPrefix="/.*"/>